# java jersey variable length paths

Tags: java, jersey

Is there anyway to specify in jersey I want a variable length paths?

e.g.

I want to implement a jersey resouce that handles e.g. the following url:

```
/images/asdfu213/size;width=100;height=200/reflect;offset=2/rotate;angle=0.45/
```

This is a variable length path as the user could append another operation on the image e.g.:

```
/images/asdfu213/size;width=100;height=200/reflect;offset=2/rotate;angle=0.45/shear;x=0.3/
```

is there anyway in jersey to implement this?

I have tried:

```
@Path("/{id}/{size}/{ops: .*}")
Response process(@PathParam("id)String id, @PathParam("size") PathSegment sizeSegment, @PathParam("op") PathSegment opsSegments)
```

but all the matrix params are striped, and opsSegments.getPath is empty

also tried

```
@Path("/{id}/{size}/{ops: .*}")
Response process(@PathParam("id")String id, @PathParam("size") PathSegment sizeSegment, @PathParam("op") String opsSegments)
```

although the path is preserved, all the matrix params are stripped

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry found the answer,

you can have a list of [PathSegment](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html)s like:

```
process(@PathParam("ops") List<PathSegment> ops)
```

and jersey is smart enough to handle that for you.

This is in the api doc! should have read it first.