# Path segment sequence to vararg array in JAX-RS / Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

JAX-RS/Jersey allows URL path elements to be converted to Java method arguments using `@PathParam` annotations.

**Is there a way to convert an unknown number of path elements into arguments to a vararg Java method?**  I. e. `/foo/bar/x/y/z` should go to method: `foo(@PathParam(...) String [] params) { ... }` where `params[0]` is `x`, `params[1]` is `y` and `params[2]` is `z`

**Can I do this in Jersey/JAX-RS or some convenient way?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for but you could do something like this.

```
@Path("/foo/bar/{other: .*}
public Response foo(@PathParam("other") VariableStrings vstrings) {
   String[] splitPath = vstrings.getSplitPath();
   ...
}
```

Where VariableStrings is a class that you define.

```
public class VariableStrings {

   private String[] splitPath;

   public VariableStrings(String unparsedPath) {
     splitPath = unparsedPath.split("/");
   }
}
```

Note, I haven't checked this code, as it's only intended to give you an idea.
This works because VariableStrings can be injected due to their constructor 
which only takes a String.

Check out the [docs](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html).

Finally, as an alternative to using the @PathParam annotation to inject a VariableString
you could instead wrap this logic into your own custom Jersey Provider.  This provider would inject a "VariableStrings" more or less the same manner as above, but it might look a bit cleaner. No need for a PathParam annotation.

Coda Hale gives a good [overview](http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-injection-providers).

Comment: elegant workaround; and in particular, great idea to have a reusable class to do the parsing.  i'll accept this after some time to confirm that there is no direct way. thanks!

Comment: Another thing you could do, which is more or less the same thing, is wrap this logic in your own custom Jersey Provider.  This provider would inject a "VariableStrings" object for you.  No need for a PathParam annotation.

Comment: Coda Hale gives a good overview.  http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-injection-providers/

Comment: thanks for that additional bit -- could you please edit that last bit into the main answer and i'll accept it as the correct one.  thanks!

Comment: I added the comment above as requested.

Comment: thanks very much! (it will help whoever has the same question next time) :)

Comment: For another possible solution, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903907](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903907), which shows this done using `List<PathSegment>` rather than a custom class