# Store @PathParam values from REST call in a list or array

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs, path-parameter

My function looks like this:

```
    @PUT
    @Path("property/{uuid}/{key}/{value}")
    @Produces("application/xml")    
    public Map<String,ValueEntity> updateProperty(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @PathParam("key") String key,
            @PathParam("value") String value,
            @PathParam("uuid") String uuid) throws Exception {
                                       ...
                             }
```

I have to modify it, so it accepts indefinite(or many) list of key-value pairs from REST call, something like

```
@Path("property/{uuid}/{key1}/{value1}/{key2}/{value2}/{key3}/{value3}/...")
```

Is it possible to store them in an array or list, so I do not list dozens of @PathParams and parameters, to avoid this:

```
@PathParam("key1") String key1,
@PathParam("key2") String key2,
@PathParam("key3") String key3,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be a good opportunity to rethink this design. By using `/`s, we are in a way signifying, with each `/` that we are trying to locate a different resource. Key/Value pairs (in the context of the URL) are mainly for query parameters or matrix parameters.

If `/property/{uuid}` is the path to a main resource, and we just want to offer some parameters to the client for accessing this resource, then we could allow matrix parameters or query parameters

**Matrix Parameters** (in a request url) will look something like

```
/12345;key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3
```

A resource method to obtain the values might look something like

```
@GET
@Path("/property/{uuid}")
public Response getMatrix(@PathParam("uuid") PathSegment pathSegment) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Get the {uuid} value
    System.out.println("Path: " + pathSegment.getPath());

    MultivaluedMap matrix = pathSegment.getMatrixParameters();
    for (Object key : matrix.keySet()) {
        builder.append(key).append(":")
               .append(matrix.getFirst(key)).append("\n");
    }
    return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
}
```

- See [`PathSegment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html)

**Query Parameters** (in a request url) might look something like

```
/12345?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

A resource method to obtain the values might look something like

```
@GET
@Path("/property/{uuid}")
public Response getQuery(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid, 
                         @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    MultivaluedMap params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object key : params.keySet()) {
        builder.append(key).append(":")
               .append(params.getFirst(key)).append("\n");
    }
    return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
}
```

- See [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments%28%29)

The difference is that Matrix parameters can be embedded into path segments, while query parameters must be placed at the end of the URL. You can also notice a little difference in syntax.

---

**Some Resources**

- [Query String (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)
- [When to use query parameters versus matrix parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401981/when-to-use-query-parameters-versus-matrix-parameters)
- [URL matrix parameters vs. request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters)

---

**UPDATE**

Also looking at the `PUT` in you method signature, it appears you are trying update a resource using the path as the values for which you are trying to update, as I don't see any parameters in your method for an entity body. When PUTting, you should be sending the representation in the the entity body, not as as path segments *or* parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot. I adapted your suggestion and worked nice.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround:

```
@Path("/foo/bar/{other: .*}
public Response foo(@PathParam("other") VariableStrings vstrings) {

   String[] splitPath = vstrings.getSplitPath();


}
```

VariableStrings class:

```
public class VariableStrings {

   private String[] splitPath;

   public VariableStrings(String unparsedPath) {
     splitPath = unparsedPath.split("/");
   }
}
```

[Path segment sequence to vararg array in JAX-RS / Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925135/path-segment-sequence-to-vararg-array-in-jax-rs-jersey)

Another example where you map the optional parameter to a Map:

```
@GET
@ Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "plain/text"})
@ Path("/location/{locationId}{path:.*}")
public Response getLocation(@PathParam("locationId") int locationId, @PathParam("path") String path) {
    Map < String, String > params = parsePath(path);
    String format = params.get("format");
    if ("xml".equals(format)) {
        String xml = "<location<</location<<id<</id<" + locationId + "";
        return Response.status(200).type("application/xml").entity(xml).build();
    } else if ("json".equals(format)) {
        String json = "{ 'location' : { 'id' : '" + locationId + "' } }";
        return Response.status(200).type("application/json").entity(json).build();
    } else {
        String text = "Location: id=" + locationId;
        return Response.status(200).type("text/plain").entity(text).build();
    }
}

private Map < String, String > parsePath(String path) {
    if (path.startsWith("/")) {
        path = path.substring(1);
    }
    String[] pathParts = path.split("/");
    Map < String, String > pathMap = new HashMap < String, String > ();
    for (int i = 0; i < pathParts.length / 2; i++) {
        String key = pathParts[2 * i];
        String value = pathParts[2 * i + 1];
        pathMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return pathMap;
}
```