# Pass dynamic values to rest easy web service in java

Tags: java, json, web-services, netbeans, resteasy

My web service is in Net Beans and i want to pass dynamic values to method
from Android studio

My json url is :

```
http://192.168.1.31:8084/adminWebservice/mywebservice/ShowSelectedCategory/Bar
```

My webservice class is:

```
@GET
@Path("/ShowSelectedCategory/{strRestroTypes}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<CategoryTypes> ShowSelectedCategory(@PathParam("strRestroTypes")String[] strRestroTypes)
{
}
```

My entity file contains

```
@XmlRootElement(name="restaurant")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"restroid","restroname"})
public class RestaurantTypes {

    private int restroid;
    private String restroname;

   //getter and setter   
}
```

Through this code I can only pass one parameter, and not more than that
Thanks in advance for help and suggestions

Comment: Why do you need more than a single value? What do you expect the path segment value to be? Maybe you want to instead work with [matrix params or query params](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26993356/2587435)

Comment: Data flow : When user select multiple Restaurant types, based on that Categories will be fetched and shown to Android interface.

Comment: Use query params. `/ShowSelectedCategory?type=bar&type=whatever`. Then use `@QueryParam("type") List<String> types`. You _could_ use `/ShowSelectedCategory?type=bar,whatever`, but then you need to parse the String value yourself. What you don't want to do is `/ShowSelectedCategory/bar/whatever`.

Comment: ok, I will try this and let u know, thanks