# Does any JAX-RS implementation parse path segment specific parameters and values?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I note that the last paragraph of [RFC 3986 section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) states:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications
> often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit
> scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For
> example, the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
> often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
> that segment.

I know that the standard `@Path` annotation handles patterns like
`foo/{bar}/baz` to pull "bar" as a parameter into the associated method.

What I have not been able to find is any mention of handling something like
`/foo/x,param1=baz/bar` or `/foo/x;param1=baz/bar` where the `param1` value "baz" would be passed to the associated method.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: I don't think query parameters can be in the middle of a url. Only at the end

Comment: Your example looks like you want [matrix parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26993356/2587435).

Comment: Note that there is also the `@MatrixParam` annotation that you can use just like any other `@XxxParam`.

Comment: Is there a way to split associate the matrix params with the path segment they came from:  e.g. /x;foo=baz/y;foo=bar  and associate foo=baz with the x segment and foo=bar with the y segment?

Comment: You need to use the `PathSegment` as seen in the example I linked to. Each `PathSegment` comes with the path value and all the matrix parameters in a map

Comment: If the matrix parameters suggestion was posted as a solution I would select it as the answer

Answer (score -1):

What you are referring here is hierarchical URI, which used specially in case where you have relation between resources. 
Your URI shows bar and baz is related such that for a value of bar there is resource of baz.
Lets consider you want to pass {bar} value as xyz also want to pass some parameter value to baz end point.
So your URI should look like

```
/foo/xyz/bar?param=value
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The matrix solution above seems to be closer to what I was looking for.