# How to accept list of parameter values as input in REST?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, restful-url

I want to display info about Subdepartments using multiple id's provided.This is what I have. Now, what would an example of url with multiple parameters? I tried comma, slash but didnt work

```
@Path( "{id: .*}" )
@GET
public Collection< SubDepartmentDTO > findMultiple ( @PathParam ( "id" ) List<Integer> idList ) {
    Map< Integer, SubDepartmentDTO > subList = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    int index = 0;
    while( index < idList.size() ){
        subList.put( idList.get(index), SubDepartmentDAO.findOne ( idList.get(index) ) );
        index++;
    }
    return subList.values();
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understood your question, you want to know how key/value parameter formatted/looks like in Rest?

Comment: I want to know how to specify multiple id's in the url

Answer (score 0):

You cant use an array as path parameter, see the [docs](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html), in particular:

> The type of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:
>
> - Be PathSegment, the value will be the final segment of the matching
>   part of the path. See UriInfo for a means of retrieving all request
>   path segments.
> - Be List, the value will be a list of PathSegment corresponding to the path segment(s) that matched the named template
>   parameter. See UriInfo for a means of retrieving all request path
>   segments.
> - Be a primitive type.
> - Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument.
> - Have a static method named valueOf that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String)).

If what you are trying to achieve `/resource/id/subid/subsubid` then answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925135/path-segment-sequence-to-vararg-array-in-jax-rs-jersey) will help you.

However, if this hierarchy doesn't make sense in your case and you want to get list of departments on the same level (i.e. subid1, subid2, etc), maybe you want to use [query parameter](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/index.html?javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) instead of path parameter.